# Facebook audience network creation stopped in Update Basic Settings

Tags: android, facebook

I have been following Quick Start of Audience Network in Facebook developers to create ads. In the step *Update Basic Settings*, it shows

> Update Basic Settings
>   For mobile apps: select Settings and add your Bundle ID (for iOS app) or Package Name (for Android app). For mobile websites: in the Audience Network Mobile Web box below, select Add a Domain and enter your domain. Once we receive a request for an ad, we will review where ads are appearing.

Then I go to Settings. Fill in the package name of Android and Bundle ID of iOS. When I try to save, it shows

> There was a problem verifying the package name com.momihot.colorfill on Google Play. Please check the package name and try again.
>   If your app isn't listed publicly on Google Play yet you can ignore this message.

The app's package name is com.momihot.colorfill . The package is not available in Google Play of United States. But it is available in Google Play of all other countries. After I click *Use this package name*, I still cannot go to next step in Audience Network guide. Is it the reason why I stopped at *Update Basic Settings*? What should I do to continue?